# Adding buttons in relation to row

Tags: c#

I've trying to add two button to the rows that have value 2, but these button appear only in relation to the dataGridView.

If I don't give them a specific location they will appear at the top of the dataGridView, and when I give them a specific location they will still appear in relation to the dataGridView.

How can I make them appear in relation to each row that has value 2?

I want to make the buttons appear at the bottom or inside that specific row. I've been looking for an answer for a long time and I can't find anything.

```
Button buttonOk = new Button() { Width = 100, Height = 50 };
Button buttonCancel = new Button() { Width = 100, Height = 50 };

    public void method1(DataGridView dataGridView1)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            if ((string)row.Cells[2].Value == ("1"))
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }

            else if ((string)row.Cells[2].Value == ("2"))
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                dataGridView1.Controls.Add(buttonOk);
                dataGridView1.Controls.Add(buttonCancel);   
                //buttonOk.Location = new Point(00, 74);
            }
            else if ((string)row.Cells[2].Value == ("3"))
            {
               //do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add buttons to a `DataGridView`.  You can, however, define a column as a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`.  Of course the problem is that the button will show in all the rows.  You could implement a custom `DataGridViewButtonColumn` as shown in this [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6d495e29-4569-4801-b0b1-86aae56c203d/removehide-button-on-datagridview).  With your custom button column you can now hide the buttons as desired.

Comment: That's looks like a good alternative to this problem. Ty MikeH